# Loader Manager error

Tags: android, database, loader

Whenever I call the `LoaderManager` using `getLoaderManager().initLoader()` method, I get an error for the wrong third argument type. I pass `this` as the third argument. Can anybody tell me why am I getting this error. I called the `LoaderManager` in the end of my `onCreate()` method. Here's my code below :

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int PET_LOADER = 0;

    PetCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Find the ListView which will be populated with the pet data
        ListView petListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        petListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        mCursorAdapter = new PetCursorAdapter(this, null);
        petListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        petListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);

                Uri currentPetUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

                intent.setData(currentPetUri);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(PET_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    private void insertPet() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_NAME, "Toto");
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_BREED, "Terrier");
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_GENDER, PetEntry.GENDER_MALE);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT, 7);

        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_catalog.xml file.
        // This adds menu items to the app bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to a click on the "Insert dummy data" menu option
            case R.id.action_insert_dummy_data:
                insertPet();
                return true;
            // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
            case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
                // Do nothing for now
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String[] projection = {PetEntry._ID,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_BREED};

        return new CursorLoader(this,
                PetEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` are you implementing? The one from `android.app`, or from `android.support.v4.app`?

Comment: Yeah the `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loaders are offered by both the Android framework (`android.app`) and the Android support library (`android.support.v4.app`). They're not interchangeable, so you need to choose which one to use and make sure that all of the components you're using in a given place (e.g. an activity) are from the same package.

`AppCompatActivity` offers the ability to use both - `getLoaderManager()` returns the framework component (`android.app.LoaderManager`) whereas `getSupportLoaderManager()` returns the support library component (`android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`).

As you mentioned in your comment, you're importing the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` component from the support library. The problem I think you're having is that you're trying to use that with the `LoaderManager` component from the framework (via `getLoaderManager()`).

Try changing `getLoaderManager()` to `getSupportLoaderManager()`. Alternatively, if for some reason you don't want to use the support library, you'll need to import `android.app.LoaderManager` instead.